# Trouble installing printer on Windows Vista Home Premium

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-vista, printer

I installed a USB printer driver on a laptop running Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit. The installation completed successfully, but the printer doesn't execute any print jobs and instead just gives error messages like 'access denied', 'Active Directofy Domain Service is unavailable'. I'm the owner and the only administrative user of the system. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Control Panel > Hardware > Devices and Printers > Printer properties` and go to the `Security` tab.

There are listed all the users that can access that printer. If you are under a domain you can use specific users or security groups.

If you don't want any security just add `Everyone` on the list.

[image: 1]